# how to insert pre-set filter in renderList in prestashop?

Tags: php, filter, prestashop, action-filter

As I was able to select the previous problem with a lot of help from @TheDrot, now with this came another when I renitialize the filtering it does not return with the standard filter I need some help to know what I have to change in the code to get it to work.
[result in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmNtQ.png)
I send the code and the image of the result without success.
Thanks for your help.
Thank you.
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvbEb.png)

```
public function processResetFilters($list_id = null)    
    {
        if ($list_id === null) {
            $list_id = isset($this->list_id) ? $this->list_id : $this->table;
        }

        $prefix = '';//var_dump($list_id, $prefix, $this->context->cookie);
        $filters = $this->context->cookie->getFamily($prefix.$list_id.'Filter_');
        foreach ($filters as $cookie_key => $filter) {
            if (strncmp($cookie_key, $prefix.$list_id.'Filter_', 7 + Tools::strlen($prefix.$list_id)) == 0) {
                $key = substr($cookie_key, 7 + Tools::strlen($prefix.$list_id));
                if (is_array($this->fields_list) && array_key_exists($key, $this->fields_list)) {
                    $this->context->cookie->$cookie_key = null;
                }
                unset($this->context->cookie->$cookie_key);
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{'submitFilter'.$list_id})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{'submitFilter'.$list_id});
        }
        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderby'})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderby'});
        }
        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderway'})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderway'});
        }

        $_POST = array();
        $this->_filter = false;
        unset($this->_filterHaving);
        unset($this->_having);

        //your code
       $table= 'contabilidade_faturacao';
    $startTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1  , 1 , date('Y'))); 
    $endTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d')-date('j'), date('Y'))); 
    $table = 'contabilidade_faturacao';
    $date_filter_key = $table.'Filter_cf!data';
    $this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key} = serialize(array(
        $startTime,
        $endTime
    ));
    $this->context->cookie->write();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the list not being filtered in SQL or just the list not displaying filters used in the column headers?

Comment: The filters are working perfectly, my problem is that I want to insert a filter on the date that when the user sees this list this filter is already implemented and can be modified. I have an example in the image that I put https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFDZt.png. I hope you've explained what my problem is. Thank you

Comment: Then you need to check if date filters don't exist in POST and cookie then write default date filters to cookie before generating list.

Comment: In terms of theorists I am realizing what you are saying to me, in practice I do not know how to do this. Do you know if there is any documentation I can follow?
I have then make an if to check if the filters exist in POST?
example: var_dump($_POST) ["submitFiltercontabilidade_faturacao"]=> string(1) "1" ["page"]=>string(1) "1"                                      
["selected_pagination"]=> string(2) "50"  ["local_contabilidade_faturacaoFilter_cf!data"]=>  array(2) { [0]=>string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: @TheDrot a need help please. 
I have been trying to modify the (! Tools :: getIsset ...) and reinscribe the cookie but even so it does nothing the cookie is not reeinscribed. Please help me. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.                        (...)
  $date_filter_key = $table.'Filter_cf!data';
  if (!isset($this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key})) {
   $this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key} = serialize(array(
    $startTime,
    $endTime
   ));
   $this->context->cookie->write();
  }

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering the list check if date filters are not set then write the default date filters to cookie.

```
$date_filter_key = $table.'Filter_cf!data';
if (!Tools::getIsset('local_'.$date_filter_key) && !isset($this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key}) {
    $this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key} = serialize(array(
        '2017-02-01',
        '2017-02-28'
    ));
    $this->context->cookie->write();
}
```

When you are resetting filters you have to rewrite the cookie with default filters.

```
public function processResetFilters($list_id = null)
{
    ...
    // your code
    $startTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1  , 1 , date('Y'))); 
    $endTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d')-date('j'), date('Y'))); 
    $table = 'contabilidade_faturacao';
    $date_filter_key = $this->table.'Filter_cf!data';
    $this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key} = serialize(array(
        $startTime,
        $endTime
    ));
    $this->context->cookie->write();
}
```

Comment: I put your code but nothing happened do I have to inject it after inserting the normal filters?
Thank you very much for the help and I apologize for not being able to understand but I have just started with the prestashop and I still do not know very well how to do some operations. Thank you.

Comment: You can do it after inserting normal filters. Maybe the `$date_filter_key` is not correct, check you POST and cookie data by `var_dump(Tools::getAllValues());` and `var_dump($this->context->cookie->getAll());` to find filter value for date fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but unfortunately I think it's still not resolved I did the var_dump and that's what it gave: ["remote_addr"]=>
  string(10) "1042070754"
  ["stats_date_update"]=>
  string(10) "1492556400"
  ["submitFilterproduct"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["productsproductFilter_active"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["contabilidade_movimentoFilter_cf!data"]=>
  string(28) "a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";}"
  ["contabilidade_faturacaoFilter_cf!data"]=>
  string(28) "a:2:{i:0;s:0:"";i:1;s:0:"";}"
  ["checksum"]=>
  int(1026487492)

Comment: In the cookie you don't have `local_` prefix for date filter, also the code in my answer will only work until a user filters the list for the first time. So you might want to delete your cookies to test. Also move the code before inserting normal filters. I updated the answer to handle `local_` prefix properly.

Comment: I tested it now, cleaned up the cookies it had and it works perfectly.
I just wanted to know is if I have to clear cookies when I reinstall my module?
Thank you very much, you helped solve my problem.

Comment: I'm testing various possibilities and I noticed that when I go to the list it still does not appear, but the values ​​appear as default, but when I update the list it gets the default filters. How to by the standard filters soon when we see the list?

Comment: I tried this now and it still does not work, it reboots all filters. I apologize. Thank you.

Comment: @TheDrotI edited my question with your implemented code, and inserted another image with the result obtained. If you can help me with any further suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by overriding the HelperList.php core file (Path: /classes/helper/HelperList.php)

There is a function named displayListHeader() which gets all the filters in the list and pass them to the TPL file (/admin/themes/default/template/helpers/list/list_header.tpl), which renders all the filters.

You can override the displayListHeader() function in HelperList.php class to change the behavior of filters in HelperList.

Comment: I have solved the issue by implementing the code below.
My only problems, is when I make "processResetFilters" it eliminates all the filters by default, but I do not want this to occur.
Do you have any suggestions that can help me? Thank you.

Comment: @SilviaPimenta So you need to edit `processResetFilters()` method and at the end of it rewrite cookie with default filter values.

Comment: @TheDrot, Yes, I have tried to do this, but always erases my default cookie that I need.
Is the code for rewriting the cookie what you showed me?
Thank you for your help, it has been essential. thanks

Comment: I edited my question. Please, if you have any solution that can help me, I am grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
I apologize @TheDrot, but nothing is happening, I send my code to vers and can tell me where I am missing.
I send the image of my result.[result code in image][1]
I'm sorry I'm not figuring out how I can make it work but I'm still new to prestashop.
Thank you for your precious help.

public function processResetFilters($list_id = null)    
    {
        if ($list_id === null) {
            $list_id = isset($this->list_id) ? $this->list_id : $this->table;
        }

        $prefix = '';//var_dump($list_id, $prefix, $this->context->cookie);
        $filters = $this->context->cookie->getFamily($prefix.$list_id.'Filter_');
        foreach ($filters as $cookie_key => $filter) {
            if (strncmp($cookie_key, $prefix.$list_id.'Filter_', 7 + Tools::strlen($prefix.$list_id)) == 0) {
                $key = substr($cookie_key, 7 + Tools::strlen($prefix.$list_id));
                if (is_array($this->fields_list) && array_key_exists($key, $this->fields_list)) {
                    $this->context->cookie->$cookie_key = null;
                }
                unset($this->context->cookie->$cookie_key);
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{'submitFilter'.$list_id})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{'submitFilter'.$list_id});
        }
        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderby'})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderby'});
        }
        if (isset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderway'})) {
            unset($this->context->cookie->{$prefix.$list_id.'Orderway'});
        }

        $_POST = array();
        $this->_filter = false;
        unset($this->_filterHaving);
        unset($this->_having);

        //your code
        $startTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m')-1  , 1 , date('Y'))); 
        $endTime = date('Y-m-d', mktime(23, 59, 59, date('m'), date('d')-date('j'), date('Y'))); 
        $table = 'contabilidade_faturacao';
        $date_filter_key = $this->table.'Filter_cf!data';
        if (!Tools::getIsset('local_'.$date_filter_key) && !isset($this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key})) {
            $this->context->cookie->{$date_filter_key} = serialize(array(
                $startTime,
                $endTime
            ));
            $this->context->cookie->write();
        }
    }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2peoP.png
```

Comment: This is not an answer, next time edit your question. And you obviously need to remove the `if (!Tools::getIsset...` part because when you are resetting filters those values exist in POST and the cookie rewrite code never executes.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know that it was better to edit the question. Next time I will not.
I am not realizing where I have to modify, since I have tried to modify one by one, and that never eliminates the filter of the date, but not cosnsigo, always makes reset to all filters.
Can you help me, please?
Thank you

Comment: @TheDrot, I edited my question. Please, if you have any solution that can help me, I am grateful. Thanks.